# Fonts suddenly look different and larger, Unity panel larger, notification bubbles smaller on account.

Tags: configuration, fonts

So, I have absolutely no idea how any of this happened. I first noticed that my Chromium font was different. I thought nothing of it. Then, a TON of odd things happened. All of my fonts looked very different. They were larger than normal. The panel in Unity was thicker than normal. The notification bubble was about half the size as it should be. And, to top it all off, `gnome-terminal` does not work period unless I do `gksu gnome-termial` when I press Alt-F2.

1. What the heck happened?
2. How on earth do I fix this?

This happens on GNOME and Unity.

Edit: I tried a Guest account...none of these problems exist. So, I know it has to do with my particular HOME directory settings

Comment: Gave that a try and still nothing, sadly.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. What would that do, just out of curiousity?

Comment: @Rinzwind Is that a true concern? I have often used GKSU to launch Nautilus when I need to alter files outside my Home, but I know I've browsed my home and even moved files in and out of it during this too. Should I not do this?

Comment: @neon_overload Thank you for the correct title...I was freaking out when it first happened and didn't know how to properly label it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing holding me back from Rinzwind's answer was the fact that it would take forever and it may not have been entirely successful. But I did use his basic idea in my solution.

First off, I deleted .gconf and .config out of my home directory and rebooted. Upon login, while nothing was how I had customized it, everything was default, including terminal working. I then used terminal and chmod-ed everything to be under me and NOT root.

So, while I have lost every configuration I used to have, my desktop is back in order again.

Comment: For future reference, both .gconf and .config store settings from many different applications/things.  So you could selectively restore sub-directories within these until you encounter sub-directories that make the problem re-appear if you like.

Comment: Woah, that would have made this so much easier. Would you recommend adding this to my answer?